# Formulation of a state transition matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-matrices

My transition matrix differs from that provided by the author. As this problem is part of my homework I would appreciate some help to see why my solution doesn't work.  This is exercise 17-29 from the book Operations research by Hamdy A. Taha.

[image]
[image]

This is the solution given by the author:

[image]

This is my solution:

My matrix is the same for the 4 first rows but it differs in row number 5 with that given in the solutions section.   For me there are two options for it. In the first one I think the mouse can go in either direction from 5, including the exit, which connects to state 1. So the probability for each path is $\frac{1}{4}$. This would be the matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
0&\frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
\frac{1}{3}&0 &\frac{1}{3}& 0 &\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}& 0 & 0&\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}& \frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4} &0
\end{pmatrix}

For the second alternative I think the mouse gets out and pass to state 1 as soon as he gets the exit, so the probability of passing to state 1 is 1 and 0 for the other paths. The matrix would be

\begin{pmatrix}
0&\frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
\frac{1}{3}&0 &\frac{1}{3}& 0 &\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}& 0 & 0&\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
1 & 0& 0&0 &0
\end{pmatrix}

As you can see both alternatives differ from the answer given by the author and the truth is I don't see the logic behind that answer. It seems contradictory to me that you can go to states 2, 3, and 4 with probabilities of $\frac{1}{3}$ each while being forced to pass to state 1 giving probability of 0.  It would be very helpful to see any comments and insights about it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the claimed answer has its fifth row the same as the first.

I think the author, in writing this, is concluding "well, they started at state $5$, but we will thus move them to state $1$, and thus they have the same options available there." Think of it like if the mouse starts on state $5$, they are immediately warped to state $1$, before making their choice.

Honestly, I'm not sure if this is the *best* way to handle this, but it's not one I can immediately declare invalid. My main gripe with it is that it foregoes the transitory period between states $5$ and $1$ and accounts for it none; if you interpret subsequent changes of state to be done with some time interval in-between, and consider that a critical aspect of your analysis, perhaps this needs to be accounted for (by, say, your second hypothetical answer).

I would not say your hypothetical first answer works, though, because from state $5$ the mouse can go nowhere but state $1$, by the design of the experiment.

Comment: The book solution is not correct ( because it has 5 being able to go to other places ). Yours is closer but , instead, I would just put a 1 in the fifth row and fifth column of the matrix with zero's everywhere else in the fifth row. This way, the 5 acts like an absorbing state. Once you go in, you never leave !!!!! If you let 5 go to 1, then that will kind of be an infinite loop because, from 1, one can go almost anywhere ( except 5 ) and that's not the rule.

Comment: In principle I'd agree, but part (c) of the question gets muddied if $5$ is an absorbing state, I feel like.

Comment: I'm not clear on c ? is it asking  "what is the proportion of time that one goes from (2,3, or 4) to 5 rather than back to 1 ? ".